# Why does django return the data I submitted as the HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework

So I am making Angular 8 and Django project. The scenario is that from a form in Angular, data is sent to Django to store it in a database.

```
class NewProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = NewProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewProfileSerializer

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']
        username = request.data['username']
        NewProfile.objects.create(email=email,password=password,username=username)
        return HttpResponse({'message':'Registered Successfully'},status=200)
```

The above represents my Django view. Now, seeing this, for a successful creation, I should get the `response` as 'Registered Successfully'. But what I get is the data I submitted in JSON format (basically a dictionary. I don't really know if it is json).

Why is it happening?

```
export class PostService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8000/login/';

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) {}

   getPosts(data){
      return this.httpClient.get(this.url+'?email='+data.email+'&password='+data.password);
    }

    create(url,post){
      return this.httpClient.post<any>(url,post);
    }
}
```

This is what is there in my angular service.

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.userForm);
    this.service.create('http://localhost:8000/profile/',this.userForm)
        .subscribe(response=>{
            console.log(response);
        });
```

This is the code in my `component.ts` file.

P.S.- I know I'm storing the passwords wrong way. But its just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a dict data from Django should use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). This will serializer the Dict into json and add the correct Content-Type header.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
>>> b'{"foo": "bar"}' # This will be the body sent to the client
# In your Case
>>> return JsonResponse({'message':'Registered Successfully'},status=200)
```

On the Javascript side, how you access the JSON data will vary based on the client you use to make http call. You can parse the response body using `JSON.parse(body)`, but most http clients I have used will handle that for you (Fetch API has a `response.json()` method, and I think axios gives you JS object automatically when the response is json type)

#### Note on Dict vs JSON

> the data I submitted in JSON format (basically a dictionary. I don't really know if it is json).

Dictionary is a native python type. Looks similar to JSON but they are not the same. eg. Python uses `None`, while JSON uses `null`, and many other differences like that.

JSON (Javascript Object Notation) is a way to serializer and deserializer javascript objects.

To send a dict data to your JS client as a JSON object, you would need to `json.dumps(dict)` to get the serialized json version of your dict, and then return that in the response body. JsonResponse handles the serialization for your, and also adds the "Content-Type" headers "application/json" to let your client know it's receiving a json body body that can be deserialized into a JS object.